# If $\phi_n$ is a sequence of mollifier converging to the identity, does $\inf f\ast \phi_n \to \inf f$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of mollifier converging to the identity
$$
\phi_n(x) \to \delta_{0}(x), \text{pointwise}, 
$$
with $\delta_{0}(\cdot)$ the delta function at zero, and $\phi_n \in C^\infty_{\{\text{compact support, integrate to 1}\}}$.
If $D$ is compact does
$$
\inf_{x \in D} \left(f \ast \phi_n\right)(x) \to \inf_{x \in D} f(x) \;? \tag{1}
$$

I know, in nonsmooth analysis, if $f$ satisfies some semicontinuity properties, the result holds.
Is it possible to obtain (1), through functional analysis?
I mean, if my working function space is a Sobolev space, does (1) follows?

I know
$$
\| f\ast \phi_n - f \|_{L^2(D)} \to 0,
$$
so, intuitively, I argue that the square differences being infinitesimal, (1) should holds.
Is there a rigourous proof?

Comment: A trivial nit-pick: on the right hand side you should really use the essential infimum instead of $\inf$. Changing $f(x)$ on a set of measure zero does not change $f*\phi_n$, but it can easily change $\inf f$. (Of course, if you actually meant $\inf$ then the answer is "obviously not" because of the above.)

Comment: @WillieWong I realize the mollification, I had in mind, is not the standard one. For example, the function $f(x)=1\cdot [x\ne 0] - 10 \cdot [x=0]$, can be mollified by removing point around zero and joining the 'gap' with a smooth curve. The problem becomes then different, I will think about this. Thank you.